# What audio format works for Silverlight + WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, audio, mediaelement

I'm writing a pair of applications for distributing audio (among other features). I have a WPF program that allows an artist to record and edit audio. Clicking a button then uploads this to a silverlight-powered website. A consumer visiting this website can then listen to the audio. Simple. It works. But I'd like it to be better: I need an audio format that works seamlessly on both the recording and playback sides.

I'm currently using mp3 format, and I'm not happy with it. For the recording/editing, I use the Alvas Audio c# library. It works ok, but for MP3 recording requires that the artist goes into his registry to change msacm.l3acm to l3codecp.acm. That's a lot to ask of an end-user. Furthermore mp3 recording seems rather fragile when I install on a new machine. (Sometimes it randomly just doesn't work until you've fiddled around for a while. I still don't know why.) I've been told that unless I want to pay royalties to the mp3 patent holders, I always need to rely on this type of registry change.

So what other audio format could I use instead? I need something compressed. Alvas audio can also record to GSM, for example, but that won't play back in silverlight. Silverlight will play WMA, but I don't know how to record in that format - Alvas Audio won't. I'd be open to using another recording library instead, but I haven't managed to find one.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there really no user-friendly way to record audio in WPF and play it back in Silverlight? It seems like there should be...

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh man, have you seen this - http://prefix.teddywino.com/post/SilverlightMediaKitLiveDemo.aspx? It may not answer your question, but it's pretty cool. Source code is here: http://salusemediakit.codeplex.com/

Comment: That is cool. Don't know how it would answer my question, unless they also provide a GSM version. But very cool nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, WMA would be your best bet.  I'm not sure how your application is setup or how low level you want to go, but the Windows Media Format SDK is a great way to encode WMA and the runtimes come with Windows.  There are .NET PIAs and samples for it here:  http://windowsmedianet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. That sounds very interesting - I'll dig around in it. I notice the project you gave me a link to hasn't been updated since '08. Is it still active? If the Windows Media Format SDK is simple to use, I'd expect a 10 line sample showing how to build a simple recorder, but I didn't notice one.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Ogg Vorbis is being adopted for the new HTML audio tag in *(cough)* some browsers, it's probably worth [checking it out](http://veritas-vos-liberabit.com/monogatari/2009/03/moonvorbis.html). You won't get bitten by any licensing concerns if you follow this route. If ease of deployment is top of your list, then go with WMA.

*[tries hard not to start ranting about fragmented state of codec options in browsers and the commercial interests that scupper any concensus]*